# Finding out which metas are unsolved in an Agda program

Tags: type-inference, agda, elaboration

What's the best way to find out what's causing unsolved metas? Is there a way to turn all unsolved metas (and only the unsolved ones) into holes, by expanding all the surrounding wildcards that are solvable?

If nothing else, does changing an unsolved meta into a hole make the message about the unsolved meta go away? Because then I guess I can try to change every wildcard and every implicit argument into holes until the message goes away and then figure out which one is causing the problems...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach (not necessarily the best) is to replace all implicit
arguments with explicit underscores:

```
f {_} {_} {_} (x {_} {_} {_})
```

This answer is from the Agda mailing list: https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2012/004123.html

Comment: So does that imply a positive answer to my question from the second paragraph? "does changing an unsolved meta into a hole make the message about the unsolved meta go away?"

Comment: Yes: holes are technically unsolved metas but are reported as holes instead.